# What is the verb for shy?

Tags: word-request, verbs

I know that in English I have to say "don't be shy" or "He is shy" etc. Always (at least for me) it is **be + adjective**. But I'm looking for the ***verb*** (or verbs) which denotes the same meaning and then I can use **to + infinitive** in the meaning which mentioned above.

Comment: I don't think there is a verb for this.  Shy is a state of being, not an action.  There is no verb for "he is handsome" or "he is tall" or "he is blue-eyed".

Comment: There is the phrasal verb [*shy away from*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/shy-away-from), though I don't know if this is what you have in mind. The verb forms of [*shy*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/shy_1) are basically the same.

Comment: @user3169 interesting. Honestly I've never knew that the the word shy is also verb. So actually I can say "you don't need to shy from him" or something like that? I'm asking you about it because that as a non-English speaker I've never seen a using of this verb.

Comment: @Assiduous no, it means something different, closer to "avoid" :  "The horse shied away from the bridle and ran to the other side of the corral"

Comment: Your example "you don't need to shy from him" needs to be "you don't need to *shy away from* him". But not *shy* by itself.

Comment: But according to what you linked (Collins dictionary), the word shy stands by itself as a verb, without additional phrasal part/s.

Comment: @user3169 I have certainly seen the sentence:  "the horse shied at the sight of the snake". It can certainly be used alone. See definition 2 here: http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/shy

Comment: The verb *shy* can also mean *throw* or *toss*, but this usage is not common.

Comment: Many a time I heard sports commentators(usually cricket) using _shy_ as a verb to mean _throw at a target_.

Comment: @Ganesh.R That usage of _shy_ is something of a survival. OED has: _trans. To fling, throw, jerk, toss; also with at, etc.,_ and the most contemporary quote is from 1889! I heard it used thus by my Grandfather in 1960 or so in the States ("I shied a rock at the cur!") but I haven't heard it used in 50+ years. Is that still a common contemporary usage in Indian English sport commentary?

Comment: @P.E.Dant I don't think so. I heard it mostly from non Indian English speakers(Australia, England, New-Zealand etc). They often say like _he(the fielder) shied at non striker's end_ etc. I rarely heard it from Indian commentators. I don't know what they mean actually. I heard it used like that.

Comment: @Ganesh.R . I'm always pleasantly surprised to find thriving a word I assumed was moribund.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I also heard _have a shy at stumps_ and _take a shy at something_ were used often with the same meaning in cricket commentary.

Answer (score 1):

To sum up:

The verb ***[to shy](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/shy_2)*** is used to express a sudden movement especially of an animal:

(shies, shying, shied, shied BrE /ʃaɪd/ ; NAmE /ʃaɪd/)

> - [intransitive] ***shy (at something) (especially of a horse)***  to turn away with a sudden movement because it is afraid or surprised:
>
>   - *My horse shied at the unfamiliar noise.
>       Her horse shied violently at a gorse bush.*

But probably its more common usage is in the idiomatic expression:

[shy away (from something)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/shy-away):

> - ***to avoid doing something because you are nervous or frightened***:
>
>   - *Hugh never shied away from his responsibilities.
>       The newspapers have shied away from investigating the story.*

As noted there are other less common, outdated usages:

> - ***"to throw (a missile) with a jerk or toss,"*** 1787, colloquial, of unknown origin and uncertain connection to shy (adj.).
> - "***to recoil,"*** 1640s, from shy (adj.).

Note also the expression ***[coconut shy](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shy-away-from-sth)***:

> - a game at a fair where you throw balls at a row of coconuts and try to knock them down to win them

OLD, Etymonline

Comment: To further sum up, *shy* is a verb as well as an adjective, but none of its meanings are exactly the same as "to be shy", so you can't use it as a direct replacement.